# How to make backspace work in lc3 assembly

Tags: backspace, lc3

My code is,

```
LOOP TRAP x20    ;get c
     TRAP x21    ;out
     BRnzp LOOP
```

It will output any letter to the consoles, it will return carriage, tab, but it won't backspace, and the delete button doesn't even show up in a register. Backspace will just show some character, looks like []. Delete shows nothing.

I tried another version without inputs where I used the delete ascii value and the start of text ascii value to move the cursor and delete but it doesn't seem to do anything. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Is there another way to clear the console out? I could work around it if I spam a bunch of new lines until it's off screen but I would rather it work normally. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Putting out a backspace character won't do anything to the characters already outputted, because they're already there.

The best way to achieve this is usually by setting your console to VT100-compatible (often set by default) and using VT100 escape codes to move around the screen.